# Quicken equivalent

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

I plan on switching my parents company to Ubuntu (or K or X, haven't decided yet) and one of the most important things is if there is a Quickens equivalent available for any of them?

Something to manage taxes just as well.

Comment: [osalt.com](http://www.osalt.com/quicken) is an excellent resource for this kind of question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to try `gnucash`.

```
sudo apt-get install gnucash
```

It's a good all around personal finance manager. I think it can even open Quicken files (not sure though!)

[image: gnucash screenshot]

Comment: From gnucash description: ... can import Quicken QIF files and OFX files.

Comment: Be very careful making this switch. GnuCash is capable, but it doesn't hold your hand like Quicken does. Finances are very important--make sure your parents are comfortable with it before switching.

Answer (score 5):

## [Homebank](http://packages.ubuntu.com/homebank) [image: Install homebank]

[«HomeBank»](http://homebank.free.fr/index.php) is free software. Use it to manage your personal accounts. It is designed to easy to use. Analyse your finances in detail using powerful filtering tools and graphs.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought of taking it to the cloud? I believe Quickens online version has been replaced with [Mint](http://www.mint.com/). That will free you from platform dependencies altogether. I haven't used it myself as its really targeted at US users and I am not in the US, so I can't say if it does everything your parents would need, but its worth a look.

Regarding Linux native apps, I have been looking for one myself for quite some time and just couldn't find one that would do what I needed. Financial and accounting apps in Linux are an area in bad need of improvements IMO. I finally went to the cloud with [Kashoo](http://kashoo.com), but i don't think Kashoo will do what you need hence the Mint reco

Comment: Mint is great and I use it all the time. I think it is OK for personal finance but it won't replace a real book of records because the data is frankly bad. This is an issue with the data provider that they use. Long story short, Mint is great for looking at the big picture but they are going to mis some transactions.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that [kmymoney](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kmymoney) [image: Install kmymoney] is also a good option.  It's part of the KDE family, but I've been using it with Gnome for several years.

It has a very Quicken-like interface, and it has good tools for managing multiple accounts, setting up budgets, and running reports.  I've always found its interface much more attractive and easier to use than GnuCash, too, though I realize that's a personal preference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to keep track of your transactions Internet based Mint.com does a fantastic job.  Hooked to your bank, credit card, or brokerage account it will show you every entry your financial institution makes.  You will see a charge almost as soon as it is run.  When a brokerage order settles you will see the transaction.  You will also see your account totals aggregated in one place.  Net worth is a snap if you have all your accounts in Mint.

But...  If you want to see your holdings, keep track of cost basis, or view graphs of asset allocation, forget Mint.

Quicken does both of the above and I have yet to find an Ubuntu clone:(