# Which tool to use for "home banking"?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

I would like to manage my bank accounts in a secure manner on Ubuntu.

I saw several applications in the *Software Centre*, but I don't know which one to choose. I don't need fancy features like stock options. I just have regular accounts which I want to follow, I don't want complicated stuff.

As bank data are quite sensitive, I would highly prefer an application that does encryption of the data. Though, if you have a really cool app but it does not have this feature, as long as it offers to store the data in one dedicated place, I could do with encrypting that place.

So what tool do you use that could fit my needs?

Comment: I think that should be a "comunity wiki", as there not one single possible answer.

Comment: How do you make it a Community Wiki? I tried re-editing the post but did not find the option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the most powerful solution you can use is `GnuCash`. It's not the easiest to learn, but there is quite a bit of documentation available to teach it, and it has a lot of useful features such as double-entry, hierarchical accounts, and the ability to import from Quicken. The GnuCash developers have specifically stated that they will not take on the responsibility for encryption, as it goes against their philosophy of making a program do one thing well; but they state that they are in full support of using encrypted file systems to store your data.

Comment: GnuCash is double-entry accounting which is way overkill for a personal-user.

Comment: That depends on the user ;)

Comment: Even if you decide not to use GnuCash, here's a link to the wiki answer which discusses encryption: http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_.22Can_you_please_add_a_password_feature.3F.22  There may be some good information there regarding encrypting your data.

Comment: I disagree that double-entry is overkill for a personal user. I use GnuCash for my personal books, and I love that the double-entry system takes some of the chance and guesswork out of having my books balanced at any given point.

Comment: I never heard of double-entry before, and after googling it, I'm still puzzled at the advantages for a home user.

Comment: I import banking info that has been exported from my financial institutions. When I do this, I am forced by the double-entry system to select a source/destination account. This means that all of my transactions are categorized automatically, and because GnuCash treats categories as accounts, I can see the total credits and debits from every type of income or expense account all on one screen. If it still doesn't seem compelling, then presumably it's not for everyone, but I had much less trouble balancing my books after learning how to do double-entry and using GnuCash.

Comment: I went to Gnucash, it is a lot complicated, but it had no problem almost for importing my Bank QIF files. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Always happy to help! ^_^

Answer (score 12):

## [Homebank](http://homebank.free.fr/) [image: Install homebank]

Homebank is, as the name suggests, a home banking application. It targets home users rather than businesses so seems well suited to your need.

[image: Homebank]

As far as encryption is concerned, I don't think this is an inbuilt ability. However, you can keep all of your files in a particular folder and encrypt that separately. An encrypted /home might be useful for this. Homebank does allow you to set the default directory for its files, but does not appear to stop you putting them in other, less secure, places.

[image: preferences]

See also, [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/9108/667).

Comment: Seems really nice, but it wouldn't import my bank QIF files. So I cannot use it.

Answer (score 6):

[Grisbi](http://www.grisbi.org/screenshots.en.html) is what I use, and I really find it easy and full-featured.

It allows for crypting your files if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is also [kmymoney](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/index-home.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use [wxBanker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/wxBanker)

> wxBanker is a lightweight personal finance manager. It focuses on being as simple and straightforward to use as possible.
>
> The main project page is located at https://launchpad.net/wxbanker, which contains downloads as well an Ubuntu PPA. Also linked are resources such as teams and mailing lists for translators, users, and developers.

Answer (score 1):

I found **[YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/features)** *(you need a budget)* which runs very nice in wine too. The upcoming version 5 appears to be web-based instead.

There's a free companion app for Android and iOS too, though it's not standalone, it requires you to have the YNAB software also.

This software completely turned around how I think about money! At its core it's a simple envelope system, but it emphasizes a method that looks *forward* (give every dollar a job: what does my money need to do before I'm paid again) rather than the backward-looking post-mortem of basically all other tools (what happened, where did all my money go?).

The YNAB website offers many free online classes - highly recommended. There's also a user forum but frankly the [YNAB subreddit](http://reddit.com/r/ynab) is even better.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mint.com](http://mint.com).  It is all online, which may bother some people that Mint has access to all your data, but other than that, it works really well for tracking expenses and making a budget.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a desktop application I would recommend [Mint](http://mint.com) by [Intuit](http://www.intuit.com/). Being web based it will run on any system with internet connection and can connect to most any bank, credit card, or other money service.

At this time support for international banks appears to be:

> ...financial institutions in the United States and Canada. We hope to support more countries in the future.

Which can be a pitfall for those outside of the North American continent that don't have a bank which operates in the US or CA.