# Microsoft Money alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

**UPDATE: I found [YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/features)** which runs very nice in wine too. (The upcoming version 5 appears to be web-based instead.)

---

I'm looking for something to replace my MS Money 2004 application.

- I've tried KMyMoney which seems pretty simple (that's good!) but it can't import the OFC files I get from my bank, so I would have to enter everything manually = not good.
- I've tried GnuCash which does import OFC files but I can't wrap my mind around this double-entry philosophy. It may be good for accounting but not for home use.
- I've tried to make MS Money run in Wine with some success but it was hard to make it work and I'd have to re-do that on my new machine. This is still a useful alternative for me though...

**Is there a similar tool** that **can import OFC files** and that **doesn't do double-entry** accounting? Tax capability is not needed for me, I only do after-tax numbers. Some nice dashboard views (upcoming bills, future cash flow, total net worth) and some graphs would be a definite bonus!

*Update:* I'm in Austria (Europe!) so purely US-based tools like Mint aren't relevant. Also, I really DO mean `OFC` format, not `OFX`. I have to use whatever my bank offers, even if some say it's an old format.

Comment: Related Question: [Which tool to use for “home banking”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/12734/667)

Comment: you should be careful renaming questions have people have answered for one purpose already - people start voting down the answers because those answers appear not to answer the new question.

Comment: I didn't rename the question, someone else did. And I'm going to roll-back that change because I disagree with it: My focus is not exclusively on the OFC format but on the replacement for MS Money.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the many answers I have received. I am going to choose my own answer as "accepted" though because using Money in Wine is what I honestly felt to be the best solution. I acknowledge that there are many useful native tools, but they don't *quite* cut it in terms of data import, features, and usability. But this is certainly something to review in a year or three!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the main developer of [Skrooge](http://skrooge.org/) and I would like to suggest you:

1. Try to change the extension of your file by .OFX and try to import it with Skrooge. Most of the time, it works.
2. Send me by email an example of OFC file (you can find me email in the about page of skrooge), I will add the OFC import in the application.

Comment: This is very constructive! Please give me some time.

Comment: OK, what can I do for you ? Did you try to rename the file ? Did it work ? If no, could you send me an example of file by email (you can find it in the about panel of skrooge) ?

Comment: I've finally begun using Skrooge seriously, and it is wonderful. Especially being able to make one change on several transactions at once (like setting category) is very useful. Reporting is confusing, and budgeting baffled me - but I'll spend more time with those features later on.

Comment: one thing that bothers me: all "amount" columns are formatted as "US$ 12345.67" and date fields as "MM/DD/YY" even though my system has other regional settings. Is Skrooge ignoring my regional settings because it's a KDE program running in Ubuntu/Unity?

Comment: installed Skrooge Ubuntu 17.04.  Imported OFX without a problem.  Will test Skrooge.  But, regardless of whether I adopt it or not, thank you - from one developer to another!  : )

Answer (score 6):

Firstly i assume that you are talking about OFX and not OFC since

> Open Financial Connectivity (OFC) is an obsolete file format for financial transaction information. It has since been replaced by OFX.

[HomeBank](http://homebank.free.fr/index.php) ([Click to Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/homebank))

> HomeBank is [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). Use it to manage your personal accounts. It is designed to easy to use. Analyse your finances in detail using powerful filtering tools and graphs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really did mean OFC format, not OFX. I am not the one deciding what format my bank offers -- I'm glad they offer download at all! (My old bank didn't.) HomeBank doesn't read OFC.

Comment: @torengb even microsoft money does not support ofc (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890400)

Comment: @Alaurik, that article refers to Money version 2005 and later. I'm using 2004 and the file imports perfectly. All I need to do is hit Accept for each transaction and everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 4):

As said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29931/microsoft-money-alternative/29934#29934), homebank is also a pretty good alternative.

I have had to find a similar application for my father, and I would suggest [Skrooge](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Skrooge) [image: Install Skrooge]. We eventually settled on using MS Money anyway, since I managed to get 2005 working in wine (a bit too much work) and he could just open the old files we had to recover directly.

However I would highly suggest Skrooge otherwise, as you can do just about everything you do in MS Money in it. The interface is pretty straight forward, though if you are accustomed to MS Money you may need to unlearn it.

Here is the application's website: http://skrooge.org/ - and of course the customary screenshot:
[image: http://skrooge.org/sites/default/files/images/Dashboard.preview.png]

Since I don't think it imports OFC files, I would suggest using GNU Cash to import those files, then export to a format that Skrooge can import. Once you get things converted, you will find Skrooge is rather simple and satisfying to use ;)

Comment: You're right, Scrooge doesn't read OFC. It's too much hassle for me to download the file, then import it in one app, then export it, then import it in another app -- this would be too much of a hurdle for me to do regular money management... also, it doesn't meet the WIF (wife-acceptance-factor) so I'd have to do it myself every time. Thanks though.

Comment: @torbengb :/ oh well... I'm debating whether to delete my answer, but I'm also thinking, maybe a bug report might be useful, so they can add that feature (in the future).

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Moneydance](http://moneydance.com/), which seems to handle most formats and has most of the features you ask for (including OFC import, according to their support site).  It's not free, but it's cross-platform and they have an excellent pricing scheme.

Comment: Yes! This is a good alternative. It costs 50$ but then my MS Money also cost money so that's no negative argument. And it DOES import OFC files and does so CORRECTLY!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing my copy of MS Money 2004 through Wine, and it was surprisingly simple!

The WineHQ database said to install ies4linux first, but the installation of that failed. MS Money could be installed without errors anyway, and it seems to work just as well as it did on Windows. So this looks like a winner.

Comment: could you at least mail the .ofc to the developer of skrooge.

Comment: The dev wrote a post too and I'll address him directly.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the many answers I have received. I am going to choose my own answer as "accepted" though because using Money in Wine is what I honestly felt to be the best solution. I acknowledge that there are many useful native tools, but they don't *quite* cut it in terms of data import, features, and usability. But this is certainly something to review in a year or three!

Answer (score -1):

There's also [KMyMoney](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/index-home.html), which I use.  You can import QIF files.

Comment: But my bank doesn't offer QIF. It only offers OFC. Hence my request for OFC-compatible alternatives...