# Which Finance Software would you recommend?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tool to use for “home banking”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12734/which-tool-to-use-for-home-banking)

I am trying to replace Software which I used on Windows/Mac. Know I am looking for software, which helps me track my finances and plan e.g. budgets etc. Is there any Software you would recommend for Ubuntu?

Best would be a cross platform thing, but if it is a very good one, a Ubuntu/Lunux specific one, would help, too.