# Which software program can read quicken and quickbook files?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

My credit card online account allows me to download my transaction history only in quicken or quickbook format. How can I read them under Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9108/quicken-equivalent

Comment: Yeah, I think `gnucash` will do the job for you, sir. This is first thing that showed up after installing: http://imgur.com/eUiOWVS

Comment: Well, Gnucash can import Quicken files into an existing chart of accounts. Setting this up is quite a bit more work than you would expect from "viewing my transaction history".